# How to use AutoMApper.5.2.0 With Ninject?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, automapper, ninject.web.mvc

I'm working on a large ASP.NET MVC 5 project nowadays and I'm implementing DI by using Ninject framework for MVC. Actually it's the first time to me to use Ninject and I'm in dire need to know what is the best practice of using AutoMApper 5.2.0 With it.

After Googling I found some examples which demonstrate an old version of AutoMapper that have some deprecated methods in the new version.

My solution is consist of the following projects:

1. Core
2. Data
3. Service
4. Web

I'm working on the same project in this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/crud-operations-using-the-generic-repository-pattern-and-dep/).

Comment: There is no such thing as best practice, have a read [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic). There are only use cases and business needs on how do you want/need to implement it... If you tell us some more details we could _probably_ give you some concrete answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this the project that i'm working on
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/crud-operations-using-the-generic-repository-pattern-and-dep/

Comment: In which layer do you want to do mapping?

Comment: I want to do mapping in Ioc.Web Layer.

Comment: Alright, and which parts of using Automapper is unclear to you? Please edit _all_ these details to your question!

Comment: I need to know How and Where to configure it and how to Bind it in ninject container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are three things you need to set up for AutoMapper in Ninject.

1. Bind() `AutoMapper.IMapper`
2. instruct AutoMapper to use Ninject for its services, and
3. initialize AutoMapper with your mappings.

here is the `NinjectModule` I use for this purpose:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMapper>().ToMethod(AutoMapper).InSingletonScope();
    }

    private IMapper AutoMapper(Ninject.Activation.IContext context)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.ConstructServicesUsing(type => context.Kernel.Get(type));

            config.CreateMap<MySource, MyDest>();
            // .... other mappings, Profiles, etc.              

        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); // optional
        return Mapper.Instance;
    }
}
```

then you will just inject `AutoMapper.IMapper` into your classes instead of using the static `Mapper`

Comment: btw, this is with AutoMapper 4.2.1. I hope it's not too different in v5

Comment: For those using this answer, dont forget to then register the AutoMapperModule in the kernel: `var kernel = new StandardKernel(new AutoMapperModule());`